# Is compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8' Library working in Lollipop device?

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode-scanner

I try to impliment compile `'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'`, work perfect in above `Lollipop device`, but its not working in `Lollipop`. It display white plain screen, so I want to know this library work in `Lollipop devices`?

Answer (score 0):

The barcode scanner shows a blank screen because you probably did not ask for permission to use the device's camera.

I would suggest to read through [this Android developer tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#kotlin) and then accordingly request the permission upon opening the activity.

Comment: I alredy add permission programettically @Remph

Comment: Then please show us snippet of your codes, because we won't be able to determine the cause of your problem without it.